# ¿Cómo se dice, "estructurización" o "estructuralización"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Buscando en internet, me encuentro con que algunos artículos usan una palabra y otros otra. ¿Se puede decir de cualquiera de las dos formas, o una es incorrecta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Que sepa yo, no debe ser ninguno de los dos.

Obviamente, trátase del prefijo común *-ción*. Depende de cuándo entró la palabra puede ser un *-ción* a secas, pero para neologismos, lo normal es formarlos a base de un verbo, usando *-ación* para los verbos *-ar* e *-ición* para los de *-ir*, siendo incompatible con los verbos *-er*.

Entonces, si la palabra debiese ser *estructuralización*, tendría que ser a base del verbo *estructuralizar*, que no figura registrada en el DRAE. Para *estructurización*, sería a base de *estructurizar*, que tampoco queda registrada.

Pero sí está registrada la palabra *estructurar*, significando *Articular, distribuir, ordenar las partes de unconjunto* (DRAE). A esta base podemos añadirle el sufijo *-ación*  para darle el significado de *acción o efecto de articular...*, y de hecho, dicha palabra está registrada en el DRAE:

> **estructuración**
>   1. *f.* Acción y efecto de estructurar

Nota que las dos que tienes no serían totalmente censurables, porque el sufijo *-izar* (para convertir sustantivos o adjetivos en verbos) se podría aplicar al sustantivo *estructura* o al adjetivo *estructural* resultando en *estructurizar* y *estructuralizar*, que con el sufijo *-ación* nos podría llevar a *estructurización* y *estructuralización*. Pero ya que existe el verbo simple *estructurar* y sobre todo que la se registra ya con el sufijo deseado, la mejor opción es emplear la sencilla **estructuración**.

Comment: Muy bueno tu aporte pero, a mi entender, más allá de que la palabra no esté registrada en el DRAE, es real que muchas veces el hablante tiene necesidad de crear nuevas palabras que reflejen nuevos conceptos. Una cosa es armar, organizar o dar estructura a algo (estructurar) y otra es hacer que algo sea estructural.

Comment: Curioso: el traductor de google de ingles a español lo traduce como estructuración. Sin embargo, de español a inglés, si escribes  estructuralización te lo toma como válido y te lo traduce a "Structuring".  estructurización lo toma como inválido

Comment: @gustavson precisamente, por eso puse la última parte, si bien yo no veo gran diferencia en significado entre dar estructura y hacer que tenga estructura y por ello siempre usaría la firma más sencilla. (Paréceme calco del inglés, y tampoco veo diferencia en él, aunque las tres formas disfrutan de uso según campo. La forma simple sobre todo en matemáticasby filosofía, y la más compleja en informática y psicología, y el intermedio en muchas otras ciencias naturales). Luego voy a buscar las variantes en el OED a ver qué me dice

Comment: @guifa Muy bueno eso de hacer un parangón entre el tipo de ciencia y la complejidad del lenguaje. Todo un desafío. Acabo de googlear "estructuralizar" y encuentro este interesante ejemplo que justamente tiene que ver con la lengua: "Un día Ferdinand de Saussure decidió estructuralizar el lenguaje". Nadie en este caso diría "estructurar", porque la lengua ya tenía una estructura. Lo que hizo el lingüista fue descubrir y describir esa estructura.

Answer (score 5):

Las reglas de la morfología indicarían que la palabra correcta es "estructuralización" (la acción de volver algo estructural). Mucho más común es, desde ya, "estructuración", la acción de estructurar.

- Estructura - Estructural - Estructuralizar - Estructuralización
- Diámetro - Diametral - Diametralizar - Diametralización
- Mina - Mineral - Mineralizar - Mineralización